# Tensorflow.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'arraySync' of undefined

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm getting this error both for dataSync and arraySync. The model is defined and the result is retrieved.

Code that is being executed:

```
  const result = await faceLandmarkModel.executeAsync({
     Placeholder: images_pl
  });
  console.log(result[0]);
  const emb_values = result[0].dataSync();
```

The tensor object:

```
Tensor {
 kept: false, 
 isDisposedInternal: false, 
 shape: Array(4), 
 dtype: "float32", 
 size: 716130,
 dataId: {},
 dtype: "float32",
 id: 123347
 isDisposedInternal: false,
 kept: false
 rankType: "4"
 scopeId: 283898
 shape: (4) [1, 365, 654, 3]
 strides: (3) [716130, 1962, 3]
 }
```

Anyone has any idea? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The error is saying that result[0] is undefined. It seems that there are some lines of code between the time you printed the tensor and when you want to access its value

Comment: The tensor is printed before the action

Comment: Maybe you can add the missing code to the question. But in any case, you are either assigning an undefined element to the array or removing the tensor from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tensor received from the model was not an array, and I was using the wrong model too. Sorry guys, it wasn't a trivial issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the tensor first before accessing the array within it

```
result.dataSync()[0]
```